# akka broadcast routing with remote routees

Tags: java, routes, akka

I want to build an java Akka cluster system.

the master node is expected to distributed a task to its routees.

the tasks will be performed on different nodes from the master node.

I am actually thinking of using the broadcast router.

with existing remote routees.

then will pass a remote reference of the routees to the broadcast router.

my question is is it possible to pass existing remote router reference to a broadcast router.

I have checked the documentation and looks like you anly pass the number of routers to the broadcast router.

will be happy to hear of your suggestions.

thank you all

WIll be happy to any suggestions.

thank all

Answer (score 0):

The use of given routees is shown as an example in the docs at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/scala/routing.html#Routers_In_Action, the same works for all router types.